Make the first column and grid header sticky
I am using react-window to optimize thousands of records from API.
The code works well except that the first column doesn't scroll down with the Grid. Also, The overflow of records should be the same with the Grid.
How to fix this?
Screenshots:
https://i.imgur.com/sxDeLpU.png  
https://i.imgur.com/jPVWhVp.png
Here is my code:


import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { FixedSizeGrid as Grid, GridChildComponentProps } from 'react-window';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

interface Item {
  unit_id: number;
  unit_name: string;
}

interface Data {
  id: number;
  start_date: string;
  end_date: string;
  unit_id: number;
}

interface Cell {
  row: number;
  col: number;
}

// Generate the columns (dates of the current month)
const generateColumns = () => {
  const startDate = dayjs().startOf('month');
  const endDate = dayjs().endOf('month');
  const columns: string[] = [];

  for (
    let date = startDate;
    date.isBefore(endDate);
    date = date.add(1, 'day')
  ) {
    columns.push(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  }

  return columns;
};

const columns = generateColumns();

const generateItemList = (numItems: number) => {
  const itemList: Item[] = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= numItems; i++) {
    itemList.push({ unit_id: i, unit_name: `test${i}` });
  }
  return itemList;
};

const itemList = generateItemList(1000); // Generate 10 items

const data: Data[] = [
  {
    id: 4,
    start_date: '2024-07-01',
    end_date: '2024-07-06',
    unit_id: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    start_date: '2024-07-03',
    end_date: '2024-07-06',
    unit_id: 2,
  },
  // Add more data as needed
];

// Helper function to check if a cell should be highlighted
const isCellHighlighted = (
  rowIndex: number,
  columnIndex: number,
  itemList: Item[],
  columns: string[],
  data: Data[]
) => {
  const unit_id = itemList[rowIndex].unit_id;
  const date = columns[columnIndex];

  return data.some(
    (entry) =>
      entry.unit_id === unit_id &&
      dayjs(date).isBetween(entry.start_date, entry.end_date, null, '[]')
  );
};

// Helper function to check if a cell should be disabled
const isCellDisabled = (
  rowIndex: number,
  columnIndex: number,
  itemList: Item[],
  columns: string[],
  data: Data[]
) => {
  const unit_id = itemList[rowIndex].unit_id;
  const date = columns[columnIndex];

  const isHighlighted = isCellHighlighted(
    rowIndex,
    columnIndex,
    itemList,
    columns,
    data
  );

  return (
    data.some(
      (entry) => entry.unit_id === unit_id && date === entry.start_date
    ) || isHighlighted
  );
};

const YourComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const [selectedCells, setSelectedCells] = useState<Cell[]>([]);
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);
  const [startCell, setStartCell] = useState<Cell | null>(null);

  const handleMouseDown = useCallback(
    (rowIndex: number, columnIndex: number) => {
      const origin = { row: rowIndex, col: columnIndex };
      setStartCell(origin);
      setSelectedCells([origin]);
      setIsDragging(true);
    },
    []
  );

  const handleMouseEnter = useCallback(
    (rowIndex: number, columnIndex: number) => {
      if (isDragging && startCell) {
        const newSelectedCells: Cell[] = [];
        const startRow = Math.min(startCell.row, rowIndex);
        const endRow = Math.max(startCell.row, rowIndex);
        const startCol = Math.min(startCell.col, columnIndex);
        const endCol = Math.max(startCell.col, columnIndex);

        for (let row = startRow; row <= endRow; row++) {
          for (let col = startCol; col <= endCol; col++) {
            newSelectedCells.push({ row, col });
          }
        }
        setSelectedCells(newSelectedCells);
      }
    },
    [isDragging, startCell]
  );

  const handleMouseUp = useCallback(() => {
    setIsDragging(false);
    setStartCell(null);
  }, []);

  const handleButtonClick = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('Selected Cells:', selectedCells);
  }, [selectedCells]);

  const cellRenderer: React.FC<GridChildComponentProps> = useCallback(
    ({ columnIndex, rowIndex, style }) => {
      const isSelected = selectedCells.some(
        (cell) => cell.row === rowIndex && cell.col === columnIndex
      );
      const isHighlighted = isCellHighlighted(
        rowIndex,
        columnIndex,
        itemList,
        columns,
        data
      );
      const isDisabled = isCellDisabled(
        rowIndex,
        columnIndex,
        itemList,
        columns,
        data
      );

      const cellStyle = {
        ...style,
        backgroundColor: isSelected
          ? 'rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5)'
          : isHighlighted
          ? 'yellow'
          : 'transparent',
        border: '1px solid #ccc',
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        cursor: isDisabled ? 'not-allowed' : 'pointer',
      };

      const handleMouseDownCell = isDisabled
        ? undefined
        : () => handleMouseDown(rowIndex, columnIndex);
      const handleMouseEnterCell = isDisabled
        ? undefined
        : () => handleMouseEnter(rowIndex, columnIndex);
      const handleMouseUpCell = isDisabled ? undefined : handleMouseUp;

      return (
        <div
          style={cellStyle}
          onMouseDown={handleMouseDownCell}
          onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnterCell}
          onMouseUp={handleMouseUpCell}
        >
          {rowIndex},{columnIndex}
        </div>
      );
    },
    [
      columns,
      handleMouseDown,
      handleMouseEnter,
      handleMouseUp,
      itemList,
      selectedCells,
    ]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Get Selected Cells</button>
      <div style={{ maxWidth: '1000px', overflowX: 'auto' }} className="flex">
        <div className="min-w-[300px] h-[500px] sticky left-0 bg-white z-20 mt-[25px]">
          {itemList.map((item, index) => (
            <div
              key={index}
              className="border h-[35px] border-neutral-500 flex items-center"
            >
              {item.unit_name}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div>
          <div style={{ display: 'flex', width: columns.length * 100 + 100 }}>
            <div
              style={{
                minWidth: 100,
                backgroundColor: 'white',
                border: '1px solid #ccc',
              }}
            ></div>
            {columns.map((col, index) => (
              <div
                key={index}
                style={{
                  minWidth: 100,
                  backgroundColor: 'white',
                  border: '1px solid #ccc',
                  textAlign: 'center',
                }}
              >
                {col}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
          <Grid
            columnCount={columns.length + 1} // +1 for the itemList column
            columnWidth={100}
            height={500}
            rowCount={itemList.length}
            rowHeight={35}
            width={columns.length * 100 + 100}
          >
            {cellRenderer}
          </Grid>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;




Here's how you can adjust your code:

Combine the first column into the react-window grid, but style it to
be sticky.
Adjust the styles to ensure the overflow behaves
correctly.



import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { FixedSizeGrid as Grid, GridChildComponentProps } from 'react-window';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

interface Item {
  unit_id: number;
  unit_name: string;
}

interface Data {
  id: number;
  start_date: string;
  end_date: string;
  unit_id: number;
}

interface Cell {
  row: number;
  col: number;
}

const generateColumns = () => {
  const startDate = dayjs().startOf('month');
  const endDate = dayjs().endOf('month');
  const columns: string[] = [];

  for (let date = startDate; date.isBefore(endDate); date = date.add(1, 'day')) {
    columns.push(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  }

  return columns;
};

const columns = generateColumns();

const generateItemList = (numItems: number) => {
  const itemList: Item[] = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= numItems; i++) {
    itemList.push({ unit_id: i, unit_name: `test${i}` });
  }
  return itemList;
};

const itemList = generateItemList(1000);

const data: Data[] = [
  {
    id: 4,
    start_date: '2024-07-01',
    end_date: '2024-07-06',
    unit_id: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    start_date: '2024-07-03',
    end_date: '2024-07-06',
    unit_id: 2,
  },
];

const isCellHighlighted = (
  rowIndex: number,
  columnIndex: number,
  itemList: Item[],
  columns: string[],
  data: Data[]
) => {
  const unit_id = itemList[rowIndex].unit_id;
  const date = columns[columnIndex];

  return data.some(
    (entry) =>
      entry.unit_id === unit_id &&
      dayjs(date).isBetween(entry.start_date, entry.end_date, null, '[]')
  );
};

const isCellDisabled = (
  rowIndex: number,
  columnIndex: number,
  itemList: Item[],
  columns: string[],
  data: Data[]
) => {
  const unit_id = itemList[rowIndex].unit_id;
  const date = columns[columnIndex];

  const isHighlighted = isCellHighlighted(
    rowIndex,
    columnIndex,
    itemList,
    columns,
    data
  );

  return (
    data.some(
      (entry) => entry.unit_id === unit_id && date === entry.start_date
    ) || isHighlighted
  );
};

const YourComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const [selectedCells, setSelectedCells] = useState<Cell[]>([]);
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);
  const [startCell, setStartCell] = useState<Cell | null>(null);

  const handleMouseDown = useCallback(
    (rowIndex: number, columnIndex: number) => {
      const origin = { row: rowIndex, col: columnIndex };
      setStartCell(origin);
      setSelectedCells([origin]);
      setIsDragging(true);
    },
    []
  );

  const handleMouseEnter = useCallback(
    (rowIndex: number, columnIndex: number) => {
      if (isDragging && startCell) {
        const newSelectedCells: Cell[] = [];
        const startRow = Math.min(startCell.row, rowIndex);
        const endRow = Math.max(startCell.row, rowIndex);
        const startCol = Math.min(startCell.col, columnIndex);
        const endCol = Math.max(startCell.col, columnIndex);

        for (let row = startRow; row <= endRow; row++) {
          for (let col = startCol; col <= endCol; col++) {
            newSelectedCells.push({ row, col });
          }
        }
        setSelectedCells(newSelectedCells);
      }
    },
    [isDragging, startCell]
  );

  const handleMouseUp = useCallback(() => {
    setIsDragging(false);
    setStartCell(null);
  }, []);

  const handleButtonClick = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('Selected Cells:', selectedCells);
  }, [selectedCells]);

  const cellRenderer: React.FC<GridChildComponentProps> = useCallback(
    ({ columnIndex, rowIndex, style }) => {
      const isSelected = selectedCells.some(
        (cell) => cell.row === rowIndex && cell.col === columnIndex
      );
      const isHighlighted = isCellHighlighted(
        rowIndex,
        columnIndex,
        itemList,
        columns,
        data
      );
      const isDisabled = isCellDisabled(
        rowIndex,
        columnIndex,
        itemList,
        columns,
        data
      );

      const cellStyle = {
        ...style,
        backgroundColor: isSelected
          ? 'rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5)'
          : isHighlighted
          ? 'yellow'
          : 'transparent',
        border: '1px solid #ccc',
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        cursor: isDisabled ? 'not-allowed' : 'pointer',
      };

      const handleMouseDownCell = isDisabled
        ? undefined
        : () => handleMouseDown(rowIndex, columnIndex);
      const handleMouseEnterCell = isDisabled
        ? undefined
        : () => handleMouseEnter(rowIndex, columnIndex);
      const handleMouseUpCell = isDisabled ? undefined : handleMouseUp;

      return (
        <div
          style={cellStyle}
          onMouseDown={handleMouseDownCell}
          onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnterCell}
          onMouseUp={handleMouseUpCell}
        >
          {rowIndex},{columnIndex}
        </div>
      );
    },
    [
      columns,
      handleMouseDown,
      handleMouseEnter,
      handleMouseUp,
      itemList,
      selectedCells,
    ]
  );

  const headerRenderer = useCallback(
    ({ columnIndex, style }) => {
      const headerStyle = {
        ...style,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        border: '1px solid #ccc',
        textAlign: 'center',
        zIndex: columnIndex === 0 ? 1 : 'auto',
        position: 'sticky',
        top: 0,
      };

      if (columnIndex === 0) {
        return (
          <div style={headerStyle}>
            <div style={{ width: 100 }}></div>
          </div>
        );
      }

      return (
        <div style={headerStyle}>
          {columns[columnIndex - 1]}
        </div>
      );
    },
    [columns]
  );

  const itemRenderer = useCallback(
    ({ rowIndex, style }) => {
      const itemStyle = {
        ...style,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        border: '1px solid #ccc',
        textAlign: 'center',
        zIndex: 1,
        position: 'sticky',
        left: 0,
        width: 100,
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
      };

      return (
        <div style={itemStyle}>
          {itemList[rowIndex].unit_name}
        </div>
      );
    },
    [itemList]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Get Selected Cells</button>
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', overflow: 'auto' }}>
        <Grid
          columnCount={columns.length + 1}
          columnWidth={100}
          height={500}
          rowCount={itemList.length}
          rowHeight={35}
          width={columns.length * 100 + 100}
          fixedColumnCount={1}
          fixedRowCount={1}
          itemData={{ columns, itemList, selectedCells, data }}
          innerElementType={({ children, style, ...rest }) => (
            <div {...rest} style={{ ...style, width: style.width + 100 }}>
              {children}
            </div>
          )}
        >
          {({ columnIndex, rowIndex, style }) => {
            if (rowIndex === 0) {
              return headerRenderer({ columnIndex, style });
            }

            if (columnIndex === 0) {
              return itemRenderer({ rowIndex, style });
            }

            return cellRenderer({
              columnIndex: columnIndex - 1,
              rowIndex,
              style,
            });
          }}
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;




Hi, thank you for your answer. Have you tried on your end? When I tested on my pc, it shows like this:
https://i.imgur.com/F21e2Gs.png
